# VBA codes that copy and pastes EXACT formula

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to have create two VBAs.

The first one would copy the formula of a cell (easy)

The second one would paste the EXACT formula of a cell (less easy)

Let me give you an example:

Cell A1 = A2 + A3

I want to paste the formula of cell A1 to cell, let's say, B3. But the formula has to stay "A2 + A3"

How can I do that?

Cheers,

Answer (score 1):

Simply write the source cell formula to the destination cell:

```vb
Sub Test()
    Range("B3").Formula = Range("A1").Formula
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks but how can I make this code dynamic?

ActiveCell.Formula = Range("B1").Formula
But I would like my B1 cell to be my selection.copy cell from my previous "CTRL+C" manipulation

The code should be dynamic such as I don't have to modify my range cell every time. I just want it to take the very previous cell I have copied

Comment: Copy/Paste doesn't work that way with formulas, unless the source cell formula only uses absolute references.